# Passing a Selected Row to Another Table View Controller With NSFetchedResultsController and CoreData

Tags: ios, tableview, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nsmanagedobjectcontext, cells

I have a bit of a lack of understanding with this issue and any assistance would be appreciated.

I have a Table View with a plus button; the user is presented with a Modal View and then inserts some text into the text fields. When they click save, that gets added to the Core Data database and saved into the Table view.

That is no problem at all.

What I want to achieve is allow the user to click on any cell and for a new Table View to be pushed on with THAT particular entry in mind displaying more information about that cell that was clicked. With this, I'd want to set the title of the new view controller to be the selected row's information, etc.

I understand the concept and I understand this doesn't seem that difficult to achieve, but with this being my first app, I'm overlooking a few basic concepts and I'm finding it hard to get my head around this concept.

The first question is: do I implement didSelectRowAtIndexPath or prepareForSegue?

The NSManagedObjectContext is being used from the App Delegate and so I'm looking to pass the selected cell's information so that information can be displayed from the Core Data while changing the title of the view controller.

Through reading multiple questions and resources, I do not seem any closer to understanding how I would go about achieving this.

Would I have to create a property in the new view controller to "hold" the passed value?

I'm lost with this so any assistance would be massively appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The method didSelectRowAtIndexPath is called when the user selects a cell. This way, your app will know which cell the user is selecting and from there, you can work with the informations from that cell of trigger actions after the user selected the cell.

The method prepareForSegue is called when you say to your app to go to the other View Controller using

```
 [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"YourIdentifier" sender:self].
```

On prepareForSegue, you will set the destination View Controller and which informations you wanna pass through BEFORE that app change views. It's important to know that you need to create properties (NSString, NSArray etc) on your destination View Controller to have access on the first one.

If I understood your question, you can call [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"YourIdentifier" sender:self] when the user select a row (didSelectRowAtIndexPath) and then,set the informations you wanna show on your second view controller.

Tell me if you need sample code. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks very much scollaco! That's extremely helpful! I'm still a little confused, but that does point me in the right direction. I'm not entirely sure which method I'd use in my app. I only need to pass the selected cell to the next view and it'll always be the same view controller that I pass it to.. once I pass the cell, I'd be able to use the fetch request and predicates to display just the information for that cell from core data.. any sample code would be immensely helpful because I'm still a bit lost! Thanks

Comment: What kind of object you need to pass? NSArray, NSString, NSDictionary? I'm asking just to write some sample code  :)